# Selecionar div pai ao clicar no elemento filho

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá, estou tendo dificuldade em selecionar um elemento pai quando seu filho é clicado/selecionado.

Tenho uma div principal que cuida do alinhamento de uma imagem que está dentro dela, essa imagem quando clicada, pode ser redimencionada, porém quando clico nela, a div pai não é selecionada, com isso, não consigo setar a div com o alinhamento correto.

```
<div style="text-align: left;">
  <img src="imagem" class="ui-imagem-redimensionar" draggable="false" tabindex="0" style="width: 447px; height: 494px; margin: 0px 0px 5px; resize: none; position: relative; zoom: 1; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; pointer-events: auto;">
</div>
```

Tentei criar um evento com jQuery para quando a imagem receber o foco setar o foco no parent dela, mas não tive sucesso.

```
$(document).on('focusin', '.ui-imagem-redimensionar', function () {
  $(this.parentElement).focus();
});
```

Tentei também usar CSS `pointer-events: none;` e `z-index: -1;` na minha imagem, só que ai minha imagem não é mais selecionavel e não consigo redimencionar.

Alguem tem alguma idéia, espero ter sido claro no meu problema

Answer (score 0):

Tem dois pontos aqui:

- o evento "focusin" está entrando com o focus num elemento, então não vai conseguir mudar para outro sem cancelar o evento atual dentro do mesmo handler, para isso é necesário cancelar o evento;
- para o `DIV` receber *focus*, vamos adicionar o atributo "tabindex".

Aqui um exemplo:

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.ui-imagem-redimensionar', function (event) {
  // esse comando vai cancelar o evento que dá focus à imagem, e permitir dar focus no div
  event.stopPropagation();

  var $div = $(this).parent("div");
  $div.focus();
});
```

```css
/* para demonstrar que o div recebeu focus */

div:focus {
    border: solid 10px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="text-align: left;" tabindex="0">
  <img src="imagem" class="ui-imagem-redimensionar" draggable="false" tabindex="0" style="width: 447px; height: 494px; margin: 0px 0px 5px; resize: none; position: relative; zoom: 1; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; pointer-events: auto;">
</div>
```